# CORS content-type

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications, cors

I'm working on interfacing with a third-party web server. I need to basically send http requests from my web app to their server, which requires cross origin support. Initially, the server didn't support cors, so I used fiddler to modify the responses while they worked on adding Cors support.

This allowed me to continue working. Now, they're saying they support Cors, but only for simple requests. Options (preflight) still respond with a 405.

My question is, is it possible to force all cors requests to be simple requests? Appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: What do you mean with simple requests?

Comment: @RandallValenciano — The standard meaning of the term. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, is it possible to force all cors requests to be simple requests?

Only by removing the conditions which make them complex in the first place. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests).

> A simple cross-site request is one that meets all the following
>   conditions:
>
> The only allowed methods are:
>
> - GET
> - HEAD
> - POST
>
> Apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (e.g.
>   Connection, User-Agent, etc.), the only headers which are allowed to
>   be manually set are:
>
> - Accept
> - Accept-Language
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
>
> The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

Comment: I appreciate the input. I was anticipating that changing response types (from xml to plain text for example) would be a bigger deal than it was.